# Is there a better way than GOTO in this scenario?

Tags: c#

Let's start this with a little honesty. I am not a fan of `goto`, but neither am I a fan of repeating my code over and over. Anyway, I hit this scenario. It's unusual, but not out of this world. I can't help but wonder if this is a good scenario for `goto`. Is there a better way?

```
public Task Process(CancellationTokenSource token)
{
    await SpinUpServiceAsync();
    foreach (var item in LongList())
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) goto cancel;
        await LongTask1(item);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) goto cancel;
        await LongTask2(item);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) goto cancel;
        await LongTask3(item);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) goto cancel;
        await LongTask4(item);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) goto cancel;
        await LongTask5(item);

        continue;
        cancel:
        {
            Log($"Cancelled during {item}");
            await SpinDownServiceAsync();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the next best alternative I see:

```
public Task Process(CancellationTokenSource token)
{
    await SpinUpServiceAsync();
    foreach (var item in LongList())
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Log($"Cancelled during {item}");
            await SpinDownServiceAsync();
            return;
        }
        await LongTask1(item);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Log($"Cancelled during {item}");
            await SpinDownServiceAsync();
            return;
        }
        await LongTask2(item);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Log($"Cancelled during {item}");
            await SpinDownServiceAsync();
            return;
        }
        await LongTask3(item);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Log($"Cancelled during {item}");
            await SpinDownServiceAsync();
            return;
        }
        await LongTask4(item);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Log($"Cancelled during {item}");
            await SpinDownServiceAsync();
            return;
        }
        await LongTask5(item);
    }
}
```

But look at that needless repetition.

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Can you have a List<LongTask> and just loop through them perhaps recursively, if required, still utilizing await statements?

Comment: There is always a better way than `goto`...

Comment: I haven't used a goto in years and years.  Funny though, if you decompile IL code, you'll see goto statements even if you didn't put them in the source.

Comment: How did you learn goto before break or exception throwing?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with goto.  it's not even that messy in this context.  There are plenty of other ways to do this but goto is one of the cleanest.

Comment: Thank you @MatthewWhited, I feel like the goto-hate is social and not technical sometimes. Looking at the answers so far, they seem so much more complex and more difficult to read for a poor maintenance developer.

Comment: Can't these tasks run in parallel or are they dependant on order/mutate state of item?  You could just use Task.WaitAll with all of your tasks and pass in the cancellation token.  It would get rid of the gotos and could run faster.

Comment: Task 1 backs-up, Task 2 processes DRM, Task 3 validate changes, Task 4 records changes, Task 5 deleted backup. Rough to get those out of order!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't have an exact type for LongTask1-5 but I'd do this.

```
public Task Process(CancellationTokenSource token)
{
    SOMETYPE[] tasks = new SOMETYPE[] {LongTask1, LongTask2, LongTask3, LongTask4, LongTask5};
    await SpinUpServiceAsync();
    foreach (var item in LongList())
    {

        foreach(var task in tasks){
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested) {
                Log($"Cancelled during {item}");
                await SpinDownServiceAsync();

                return;
            }
            await task(item);
        }



    }
}
```

This approach puts the tasks in an array. If the requirements change, and more tasks are needed, then the array definition gets longer but the rest of the code stays the same. Good code uses loops for repetitive tasks, and NOT lots of copy-and-paste such as is in the original post.

Comment: good solution! but it have minor bugs, you can copy my fixes ;-)

Comment: I have to say, your solution is way more complex, generally harder to read, and I just can't figure out what problem you are solving with it.

Comment: You don't need the exit car if you are using return from within the loop.

Comment: See footnote above for my rationale.

Answer (score 1):

ok, it's my new version (it can be compiled)

prepare code (hacked)

```
class TypeOfItem { }

async Task LongTask1(TypeOfItem item) { }
async Task LongTask2(TypeOfItem item) { }
async Task LongTask3(TypeOfItem item) { }
async Task LongTask4(TypeOfItem item) { }
async Task LongTask5(TypeOfItem item) { }

async Task SpinUpServiceAsync() { }
async Task SpinDownServiceAsync() { }

IEnumerable<TypeOfItem> LongList() { yield break; }

void Log(string text) { }
```

and the solution:

```
private async Task<bool> CancelAt(TypeOfItem item)
{
  Log($"Cancelled during {item}");
  await SpinDownServiceAsync();
  return false; // cancel
}

public async Task<bool> Process(CancellationTokenSource token)
{
  await SpinUpServiceAsync();

  foreach (var item in LongList())
  {
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return await CancelAt(item);
    await LongTask1(item);

    if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return await CancelAt(item);
    await LongTask2(item);

    if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return await CancelAt(item);
    await LongTask3(item);

    if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return await CancelAt(item);
    await LongTask4(item);

    if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return await CancelAt(item);
    await LongTask5(item);
  }
  return true; // all done
}
```

@codenoire: good solution, but needed some fixes... :-)

```
public async Task Process(CancellationTokenSource token)
{
  var tasks = new Func<TypeOfItem, Task>[] { LongTask1, LongTask2, LongTask3, LongTask4, LongTask5 };
  await SpinUpServiceAsync();
  foreach (var item in LongList())
  {
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
      if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        Log($"Cancelled during {item}");
        await SpinDownServiceAsync();
        return;
      }
      await task(item);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way...

```
public async Task Process(CancellationTokenSource token)
{
    await SpinUpServiceAsync();
    bool cancel;
    YourObject item;
    foreach (var i in LongList())
    {
        item = i;
        cancel = true;
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) break;
        await LongTask1(item);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) break;
        await LongTask2(item);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) break;
        await LongTask3(item);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) break;
        await LongTask4(item);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) break;
        await LongTask5(item);

        cancel = false;
    }

    if (cancel)
    {
        Log($"Cancelled during {item}");
        await SpinDownServiceAsync();
        return;
    }
}
```

... cleaner ...

```
public async Task Process(CancellationTokenSource token)
{
    var tasks = new Func<YourItem, Task>[] { LongTask1, LongTask2, LongTask3, LongTask4, LongTask5 };
    await SpinUpServiceAsync();
    foreach (var item in LongList())
    {
        foreach(var task in tasks)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Log("Cancelled during {item}");
                await SpinDownServiceAsync();
                return;
            }
            await task(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: argh the same bug as my solution: lost `item` in the Log-line

Answer (score 0):

Pretty the same as @codenoir, but I would prefer to write it like that:

```
private Action<TypeItem>[] _longTasks = new Action<TypeItem>[]
// Not sure about the type
// that could be also something like Func<TypeItem, Task>
    {
        LongTask1,
        LongTask2,
        LongTask3,
        LongTask4,
        LongTask5
    };

public async Task Process(CancellationTokenSource token)
{
    await SpinUpServiceAsync();
    foreach (var item in LongList())
        foreach (var longTask in _longTasks)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                return Cancel(item);
            await longTask(item);
        }
}

private async Task Cancel(TypeItem item)
{
    Log($"Cancelled during {item}");
    await SpinDownServiceAsync();
}
```

*It seems that you are missing async keyword in your method too.*

Comment: This assumes LongTask1-5 are already defined while the class constructor is executing.  They COULD be passed in to the Process method, but both your scenario and passing them in (as arguments) are totally different approaches.

Comment: True, but since it's a class variable, it's still possible to assign it later, and you get approximately in the same scenario. Anyway, I'm happy to see that I'm not alone to do things like that x)

Comment: That's only half-correct.  You'd have to reassign the entire array of Action<TypeItem> either all at once or index-by-index, because by default it would contain {null, null, null, null, null} if those LongTask variables were null.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. You think that LongTask1-5 could refer to many variables instead of real methods. Yeah, in that case I would have a problem, but either you, since your array will be not refresh during the process.

Comment: Yep!  "Defensive programming"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and refresh my memory about I have to learn about "Defensive programming". x)

Answer (score -2):

You could simply surround the block of `if`s in a try/catch statement, and just throw an exception when a cancellation is pending.

pseudocode:

```
function {
 try {
   for (loop conditions) {
     do_stuff_or_throw_exception1();
     do_stuff_or_throw_exception2();
     ...
     do_stuff_or_throw_exceptionN();
   }
   catch (exception) {
     log_stuff();
     shut_down()
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Using exceptions to control program flow is as smelly as using `goto`s...

Comment: No it's not.  They are totally fine.

Comment: @JoshPart I can't agree with you. This is kind of the "classical" case where you want to have exceptions: Something interrupts the expected program flow, so you need to leave that flow, do some cleanup, and end what you're currently doing.

Comment: @MarcusMüller in this case the expected program flow **should include** both the whole process **and** cancellation; I agree something unexpected can happen during the process and that exception should be controlled, and I agree there are cases where exceptions are not only useful but the better option; but overall, if there's something your program is supossed to do, it should not be considered an exception.

Comment: @JoshPart I humbly disagree – I can't see why this using an exception here has any drawbacks

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm mostly talking about "program design" and "good practices"; but if you want an actual draw back of this approach, is that it requires each and every task to check for the cancellation request, wich is what OP wants to avoid.